# Async EnableRule for Ribbon blocks rendering

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have an EnableRule (JS) for a ribbon button. Because it calls an api, it takes a bit and hence, should be async. The following implementation ilustrates the problem:

```
export async function ribbonEnabled():Promise<boolean> {
   setInterval(() => {console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())}, 1000);
   await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 7000));
   console.log('sleep is over');
   return true;
}
```

Even tough the function is declared as async and awaits the api call (or in the example the timeout), the ribbon is not rendered until a value is returned.

Here you can see that several seconds have passed and no ribbon is rendered:
[image]

And as soon as the await procedure is over, the message gets printed and the ribbon is rendered:

[image]

Is that a known issue? Are there any workarounds? I have seen solution where the function is synchronous, returns a boolean variable and in a promis changes this variable and calls ui.refreshRibbon. But this is not adviced and runs the whole function again, so more logic is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can return promise object in your function. This is only support in Unified Interface.

```
function EnableRule()
{
   const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open('GET', '/bar/foo');

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
   {
       request.onload = function (e)
       {
           if (request.readyState === 4)
           {
               if (request.status === 200)
               {
                   resolve(request.responseText === "true");
               }
               else
               {
                   reject(request.statusText);
               }
           }
       };
       request.onerror = function (e)
       {
           reject(request.statusText);
       };

       request.send(null);
   });
}
```

**Notice** If the promise does not resolve within 10 seconds, the rule will resolve with a false value.

You can get more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/define-ribbon-enable-rules)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried returning a promise. same effect. I think this is because async in JS is just syntactic sugar for promises.
I tried it in e unified interface.  But we also have a "web" interface active. Maybe this interferes?